# ILogger is not injected when using new DI functionality - Azure Functions

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

`ILogger` is not injected when using new DI functionality and not showing the log information in the console.

```
public class SampleGreeter : IGreeter
{
    private readonly ILogger<SampleGreeter> logger;

    public SampleGreeter(ILogger<SampleGreeter> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public string CreateGreeting(string name)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Logging from greeter");
        return $"Hello, {name}. I'm a sample greeter.";
    }
}
```

Nothing is logged from greeter, while logging from function runtime works and is showing in the console.

`host.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
      "applicationInsights": {
        "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
        "logLevel": {
          "default": "Information",
          "<namespace>": "Information"
        },
        "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us how you've configured the logger. Also, you say it's not injected - does that mean you get a `NullReferenceException` at `logger.LogInformation("Logging from greeter");`?

Comment: @Xerillio not getting any NullReferenceException

Comment: Then what do you mean by "ILogger is not injected"? Clearly something is injected, otherwise that line would fail.

Comment: @Xerillio injected but log information logger.LogInformation("Logging from greeter"); not showing in function app console output

Comment: Check your host.json to validate the default log level.

Comment: @user1672994 host.json file added please check

Comment: @Ramakrishna.p - add the default logLevel in logging section `"logLevel": {
      "default": "Information"
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft documentation says:
"The host injects ILogger and ILoggerFactory services into constructors. However, by default these new logging filters are filtered out of the function logs. You need to modify the host.json file to opt-in to additional filters and categories." 
[Microsoft documentation and example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection?irgwc=1&OCID=AID2000142_aff_7593_1243925&tduid=%28ir__fvngwru60kkfqmhckk0sohz3wf2xpmdjny0vstgz00%29%287593%29%281243925%29%28a1LgFw09t88-VxM1HrtPip7XzJD.dXaofQ%29%28%29&irclickid=_fvngwru60kkfqmhckk0sohz3wf2xpmdjny0vstgz00#ilogger-and-iloggerfactory)

Answer (score 0):

You've put

```
"logLevel": {
  "default": "Information",
  "<namespace>": "Information"
},
```

(and `fileLoggingMode`) within the `applicationInsights` level, but that's not the right one: it should be one level higher, as in the [sample configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#sample-hostjson-file):

```
"logging": {
  "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
  "logLevel": {
    "default": "Information",
    "<namespace>": "Information"
  },
  "applicationInsights": {
    "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
    "samplingSettings": {
      "isEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```